# Request Headers.append not working

Tags: javascript, http, jasmine, karma-jasmine, fetch

## Solution

I wanted to post the actual modified code and solution. I had to `get` the `Content-Type` individually.

```
const url = 'api/test';
const result = ApiRequestFactory.build(ApiRequestFactory.MusiQuestApiType, url);
const contentType = result.headers.get('Content-Type');

expect(result).not.toBeNull('The result is null.');
expect(result.url).toBe(urlJoin(config.MusiQuestApi.url, 'api/test'), 'The url is incorrect.');
expect(result.options).toBeFalsy('There is an options object and should not be.');
expect(result.credentials).toBe('omit', 'The credentials is not set to omit.');
expect(contentType).toBeTruthy('The Content-Type header is missing.');
expect(contentType).toBe('application/json', 'The Content-Type header is not set to application/json.');
expect(result.method).toBe('GET', 'The method is not set to GET.');
expect(result.mode).toBe('cors', 'The mode is not set to cors.');
```

### Environment

- **Test Runner:** Karma
- **Test Framework:** Jasmine
- **Test Browser:** Chrome
- **Fetch Polyfill:** [isomorphic-fetch](https://github.com/matthew-andrews/isomorphic-fetch)
- **ES6 Promise Library:** [es6-promise](https://github.com/stefanpenner/es6-promise)

### Problem

When testing the object that comes back from `defaultHeaders.values()` I get an empty object even though I `append` a header.

### Code

I have a class that builds a `Request` object. You can see below it adds a default `header` for `Content-Type` when building the object.

```
export default class MusiQuestApiRequest {
  static build(url, body, options) {
    const defaultCredentials = 'omit';

    let defaultHeaders = new Headers();
    defaultHeaders.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    const defaultMethod = 'GET';
    const defaultMode = 'cors';

    let init = {
      credentials: options.credentials || defaultCredentials,
      headers: options.headers || defaultHeaders,
      method: options.method || defaultMethod,
      mode: options.mode || defaultMode
    };

    if (body) {
      init.method = options.method || 'POST';
      init.body = JSON.stringify(body);
    }

    return new Request(url, init);
  }
}
```

But when I check for the `Content-Type` property on the `values` object I get undefined because the `values` object returned is empty.

```
const url = 'api/test';
const result = ApiRequestFactory.build(ApiRequestFactory.MusiQuestApiType, url);
const headersResult = result.headers.values();
console.log('headersResult:', JSON.stringify(headersResult));

expect(result).not.toBeNull();
expect(result.url).toBe(urlJoin(config.MusiQuestApi.url, 'api/test'));
expect(result.options).toBeFalsy();
expect(result.credentials).toBe('omit');
expect(headersResult).toBeTruthy('headers missing');
expect(headersResult['Content-Type']).toBeTruthy('Content-Type missing');
expect(headersResult['Content-Type']).toBe('application/json');
expect(result.method).toBe('GET');
expect(result.mode).toBe('cors');
```

What did I do wrong here? Seems pretty straight forward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`result.headers` is a `Headers` object which is a bit different from a plain JavaScript object.  To retrieve a value from the headers object you can use the `get` function.

For example:

```
myHeaders.get('foo')
```

Alternatively you can use `values` to return an `Iterator` which will enable you to use a `for...of` loop to extract the values.

You can find more information [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Headers).

Hope this helps.

Comment: I hope someone can explain this answer to me, because it doesn't explain the solution. The questioner assigns the header object exactly as in: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/Request. I understand you can't just get the headers object as in `headers.prop` but why can't you assign it to a request, since that's what it's made for?

Comment: Same question I have @jimboweb I am facing the same issue. Why creating a dedicated Headers object is not assignable to request construct.